# Reducing the size of magnetic components

Tags: power-supply, transformer, switch-mode-power-supply

I read some documents and papers and found a couple methods to reduce the size of magnetic components.

- Recycling the energy stored in parasitic elements such as transformer leakage inductance, switches Coss, etc., to enable high switching frequencies and reduce energy store.
- Maximizing the direct energy transfer (case of non-isolated converters) or forward energy transfer in the case of isolated converters.

I don't very understood these two items. Could someone please explain it to me?

1. Why we can increase the switching frequency when we reduce the energy stored in parasitic elements?
2. Why could the forward energy transfer reduce the transformer size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *why we can increase the switching frequency when we reduce the energy
> stored in parasitic elements*

The power output of a converter is the switching frequency multiplied by the energy transferred in each switching cycle. It's a simple case of how many joules per second we are transferring from input to output and, of course, joules per second are watts.

So, if the switching frequency is higher, we can transfer a lower energy in each switching cycle.

> *why the forward energy transfer could reduce the transformer size?*

This is how conventional transformers work and, we wind them so that the magnetization current is as negligible as we can make it. In different words: we wind them with a high inductance primary and secondary (compared to a flyback converter).

A flyback transformer stores energy and then transfers it and, the size of the core is dependent on how much energy it can store. In a conventional (or forward converting transformer) we try and store as little energy as possible.

<sub>In case you didn't realize, in a conventional transformer, the output secondary current to a load and the input current into the primary due to the load produce totally cancelling flux in the transformer core hence, the core can be smaller than a flyback transformer's core.</sub>

Comment: Thanks. very clear expalnation.

Answer (score 2):

Each half cycle the transformer effectively has to store the energy to be transferred ina magnetic field.  Increasing the frequency means more transfers, each with less energy.  Thus the peak energy stored is less, and the transformers can be smaller (though losses may be higher, depending on theaterial).

Give the importance of weight, this is why plane systems run at 400Hz not 50/60Hz

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
why ACF topology can reduce the transformer size but traditional flybakc can't do it?